# Is it possible to use the C # reflection technique with Mirth?

Tags: java, c#, .net, reflection, mirth

Is it possible to load and use functions from a .net windows dll in Mirth via reflection?

Example of how to use in .NET:

```
[Plugins.dll] => DLL name

[WPD.Plugins.WPDPluginBD.IntegraBD] => class namespace

[ExecuteImport] => resource name (function
```

Answer (score 0):

Mirth is a Java based product. You can use any Java library packaged as a .jar file, but there is no direct way to use .NET libraries. Some google searches show, that there are ways to achieve it, but it's not that simple.